# CRS not defined for ECW created in FME

Tags: coordinate-system, fme-form

I have a simple translation, from GeoTIFF to ECW in FME.  It creates the file just fine, but it does not define the CRS for the ECW.  When loading the ECW into QGIS I have to pick the CRS.  When loading it into ArcMap I get Projection  not defined warning.

In Workbench I have a GeoTIFF reader, a RasterInterpretationCoercer translator to add a transparent alpha channel, and a CsMapReprojector translator.  The source GeoTIFF uses the NAD83(2011) datum, if I reproject to NAD83 the ECW's CRS is defined, but if I set the source and destination to the NAD83(2011) the ECW is undefined.  The CRS is also undefined if I don't have the CsMapReprojector translator on the workbench.

I have tried to set the coordinate system in the ECW writer step but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Not possible > https://knowledge.safe.com/questions/21506/is-it-possible-to-write-ecw-files-with-changed-coo.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/233798/why-does-fme-reproject-to-wrong-coordinate-system-with-tifs ?

Comment: From the duplicate, can you query the properties in ER Viewer to see what it says? ECW seems to have its own naming for coordinate systems.